# How to split a String and keep the delimiter '='

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
String s = "p=YSp%hZ5=YunnYDUuGxVxAeLCZuVvSfoutO8=";
String[] array = s.split("=");
```

This array will give me an an output like this: **p, YSp%hZ5, YunnYDUuGxVxAeLCZuVvSfoutO8**

Desired would be to have those elements but keep the = sign like: **p=, YSp%hZ5=, YunnYDUuGxVxAeLCZuVvSfoutO8=**

I need to split it by = sing and keep the '=' sign somehow. Does anyone knows some pattern which will help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern...

```js
 s = "p=YSp%hZ5=YunnYDUuGxVxAeLCZuVvSfoutO8=";
array = s.split(/(?<=\=)/);
console.log(array);
```